# UITabBarController initializes with nothing selected

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a UITabBarController in my project that I'm creating programmatically - without a nib. I create the view controllers, initialize them, and then create an array of them and use the `setViewControllers:animated:` method on my tab bar controller. This works *except* that when it appears, my tab bar controller doesn't have anything selected. If I call `[ tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1 ]`, then it works just fine, but if I call `[ tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0 ]`, nothing is selected. Is this a weird bug or am I doing it wrong? This is using the iPhone SDK 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the code was written by me a *long* time ago, when I did stupid things like override the `-tabBarItem` accessor method in the UIViewController. Moving the tab bar item customization to `-initWithStyle:` fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Show your code if you will, will make it easier for us to find the problem...But from not seeing anything, what I would think is wrong is that when you initialize your UITabBarButtons you are not giving any of them an index of 0...

Comment: Please post requests for edits/addendum in the comments of the question - unless your request has a chance of actually being an answer.

Comment: Well yes it does as i state at the end of my answer, read the whole answer before commenting

Comment: I'm not finding that I need to initialize any UITabBarButtons or set their indices; it's taken care of automatically by the UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me when I set the UIViewController's tabBarItem property in viewDidLoad instead of its init method.